# How to install Visual Studio Code IDE using Anaconda?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have a Ubuntu machine. How can I install Visual Studio Code IDE?

This is the announcement but couldn't figure out how to install in Ubuntu.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2018/02/15/visual-studio-code-is-now-shipping-with-anaconda/

Can I do a conda install?

Comment: What have your tried so far? Have you tried to download Anaconda 5.1 like it says to at the bottom of the post you linked to?

Comment: You have got the wrong idea of the blog post it seems.
They are referring to support for anaconda with vscode-python extension. CHeck the extension changelog https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#conda

Answer (score 3):

You need to download and install Anaconda via their installer, at the end of the installation you'll get a prompt to install vscode. You can also install it via the navigator, check here https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/02/22/vs-code-anaconda.aspx?m=1

Comment: To install anaconda navigator use: conda install anaconda-navigator

Answer (score -3):

Download `.deb` package from https://code.visualstudio.com/ and use

```
dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
```

to install it. 
Final view looks like below
[image]

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't answer his question. They ask about using anaconda to install it.